# adding video player in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

how can i add media player without controls and border in visual basic....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the uiMode property from "full" to "none".  You probably don't need to worry about the border anymore after that.

Answer (score 1):

Winforms?  Microsoft explains how to do it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953.aspx

WPF?  Look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163455.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great player that has fully customizable controls.
[ASPNetFlashVideo Player](http://www.aspnetflashvideo.com/)